# Detect SCNBox face on which cube is lying down

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

What is the simplest solution to detect on which face (SCNGeomteryElement) the cube is lying down after applying some force to its physics body
Should I use eulerAngles? Or there is other way?

Comment: I think this can find you the 'up' side: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110918/get-up-side-of-scnnode-from-orientation

Comment: yes perfect answer. thanks.