# Extracting vertices from SceneKit iOS13 Swift 5

Tags: swift, scenekit, ios13, swift5, deprecation-warning

Updating my code to *iOS 13* and *Swift 5*, I have this **deprecated warning**:

> 'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead

Over this fragment of code to extract the vertices from a SCNGeometry:

```
/// Extracts vertices from SCNGeometry
func vertices() -> [SCNVector3] {
    let vertexSources = self.sources(for: SCNGeometrySource.Semantic.vertex)
    if let vertexSource = vertexSources.first {
        let count = vertexSource.data.count / MemoryLayout<SCNVector3>.size
        return vertexSource.data.withUnsafeBytes {
             [SCNVector3](UnsafeBufferPointer<SCNVector3>(start: $0, count: count))
        }
    }
    return []
}
```

The problem lays inside this lines:

```
return vertexSource.data.withUnsafeBytes {
    [SCNVector3](UnsafeBufferPointer<SCNVector3>(start: $0, count: count))
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44391570/8150874) gives solution here posted but there is no Swift 5 code, and I cannot come up with a solution for the warning.

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55378571/8150874) and [this thread](https://forums.swift.org/t/withunsafebytes-is-deprecated/24848) seem to give a solution but for only a value of type `UInt32` not an `[SCNVector3]` **(array)**.

Thank you all, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the warning by replacing these lines with

```swift
return vertexSource.data.withUnsafeBytes { (buffer) in
    [SCNVector3](buffer.bindMemory(to: SCNVector3.self))
}
```

That said **this code is broken**. One should never assume that the layout of the data contained in a `SCNGeometySource` (for instance assuming a direct mapping to `SCNVector3`). The `vectorCount`, `floatComponents`, `componentsPerVector`, `bytesPerComponent`, `dataOffset` and `dataStride` are necessary to correctly inspect a property source.

Comment: Seems to work just fine. I asume the problem you highlight, it's in the deprecated version of the code too, because it's assuming `MemoryLayout<SCNVector3>.size` for the components. So I will work on a safer way as you recommend. Thank you very much!

Comment: yes, my comment was more general than the warning discussed in this question. Both versions are fragile.